# Is using Everclear spirit halal or haram if used for painting cakes?

Tags: halal-haram, alcohol

I'm a baker and make fondant cakes, I sometimes need to paint the fondant in which the gel color needs to be mixed with a Everclear spirit which evaporates in the process of painting the cake for a matte finished look.

So is it haram or halal to use it?

Comment: It seems similar to the case of using spirit in Homeopathic medicine. It also evaporates and due to that it is considered halal. Although it can be argued that its being used for medicinal purposes there, but not all Homeopathic medicine are live-saving...

Answer (score 1):

Using spirit for cakes is a way you make living. The spirit evaporates and the cake is alcohol free. So it is ok.  Since there is no trace of alcohol left,it is ok to consume. It is my understanding that bakers do not use high quality alcohol in baking otherwise their cost of production goes high.

Answer (score 0):

According to Quran you should always avoid matters of doubt. If you are cent % sure that all Alcohol evaporates then its safe and halal. if it doesn't evaporate you may try to make it evaporate by little warming, or whatever technique you find best. But make sure it is halal after that, you may use blue litmus paper, if it turns red (even the slightest shade of red) then alcohol is present, else not.
if the cake is dry then litmus paper won't change color. you should take a small piece from the cake after drying it and do the test. Best of luck

Remember necessity is the mother of invention/innovation